# Prove $e^{e^{e^x}}$ is convex on $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: convex-analysis, exponential-function

I know that we can prove $f(x)$ is convex by proving the inequality $e^{e^{e^{tx+(1-t)y}}}\le te^{e^{e^x}}+(1-t)e^{e^{e^y}} \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}, t \in (0, 1)$, but I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An increasing convex   function of a convex function is convex. Just apply this repeatedly.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know this theorem.